# Tensorflow: TFRecordDataset + Embedding_lookup + Dynamic rnn -> memory leak

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-leaks, recurrent-neural-network

I am using `SequenceExample` to prepare features for sequence labeling task. The most important feature is an array containing ids of characters per input token, for example `[[0, 1, 3], [1, 4, 5, 6], ...].`

Since it is a multidimensional array I used VarLenFeature and tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense for parsing in `TFRecordDataset`, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43672956/9373240.

I feed this dense vector to trainable tf.nn.embedding_lookup and then feed bidirectional dynamic gru with this embeddings.

During training memory usage increases with batch size, goes up to 30GB for batch size of 256. Also, with small batches, training craches with big step number. 
I am guessing there is a memory leak but I cannot find the cause/reason. 
RunMetadata shows a huge memory usage by gradients on the bi-gru.

Also, I am getting UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory, but I am not sure whether is connected with the problem, I am guessing it is caused by mask used later in the code to account for padding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.